# Executing script from from submit

Tags: jquery, html, submit

When using a `button` this works (loader displays until page is loaded):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".loader").hide();
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(1000);

        $('button').click(function() {
            $(".loader").fadeIn("fast");
            $(".overlay").fadeIn(100);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

But if I use `Submit` it does not:

I am trying to the following to work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".loader").hide();
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(1000);

        $("form").submit(function() {
            $(".loader").fadeIn("fast");
            $(".overlay").fadeIn(100);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I have also tried without joy:

```
$(input[type="submit"]).click(function() {
```

I want it to work for all Submits on the page and so do not want to use IDs. Any pointers most welcome.

UPDATE

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
```

did the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't submitting the form refresh the page anyway, making the fade effects irrelevant?  Define "doesn't work" in this case.

Comment: The submit actually reloads the page, which is effectively refreshing it you are right. What I want is the loader to show when the submit is pressed and then when the page has reloaded the loader hidden. As I say, it works perfectly if I use a <button>Update</button> but not with <input type='submit' ...>

Comment: But if the page is reloading nearly instantly then isn't the loader still doing its job?  It seems like this "works" just fine.  The only reason you're not seeing a loader is because the actual operation happens faster than the loader does.  Is that really a bad thing?  Are you asking how to artificially introduce a delay before reloading the page?

Comment: In the debugger I can see that it is jumping these lines. And, no the page takes time to load. As I say with Button I see the loader for a few seconds, but with submit it doesn't even run the commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must prevent the default behavior of your form, otherwise it will submit (and the browser will change to the next page [the action in your form]).

To disable the `submit` action you need to use `event.preventDefault()` inside the `submit/click` function.

If you do need to submit the form - you can add a variable to check if the submittion was already prevented, and according to that to prevent (or submit the form within the `submit` function):

```
var submitPrevented = false;
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    if (!submitPrevented) {
        submitPrevented = true;
        e.preventDefault()
    }
    $(".loader").fadeIn("fast");
    $(".overlay").fadeIn(100);
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.submit();
    }, 1000);
});
```

> Notice that I added the `e` element as a parameter to the function.

Regarding the last code you wrote - there is a syntax error there. This is the correct syntax:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks but this prevents the form from posting. As I say it works fine if I use <button> but not <input type='submit' ...>

Comment: Thanks. More than is actually necessary as I always want the page form to post. Simply putting function(e) rather than function () does the trick. I appreciate the pointer.